# Rails: Skip validation on autosave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I have model A that has another models B, C, D associated one to one. When I create the record of A, I want to create also B, C and D instances, and skip validations for theese three. Is it possible to do in some elegant way in Rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found I can define it on "parent" mode like follows:

```
class GrantApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
     ...
     belongs_to :budget, validate: false, autosave: true
     ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in create action to call save method with "validate: false" option. If you want to keep validation in class A, you can try to skip validations in class B, C, D with "if" statement in each model. For example. `validates :filed, unless: :new_record?`